# Is there an error in this Wikipedia article: "Landau quantization"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, potential, gauge

I am trying to do a homework, so I had to consult this Wikipedia article [Landau Quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization) where it is mentioned that for the symmetric gauge $\vec{\textbf{A}} = \frac{1}{2}(-\textbf{B}y, \textbf{B}x, 0)$, we can quantize the system.

Now definition of Hamiltonian is
$$H = \frac{(p_x-qA_x)^2 + (p_y-qA_y)^2 + (p_z-qA_z)^2}{2m}.$$

The thing is, in the images below from that wikipedia article, if you think of partials , e.g $-i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ as $p_x$ it seems to me that $p_x - qA_x$ in the Hamiltonian must be written as $-i\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{y}{2}$ rather than $-i\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \frac{y}{2}$ and similarly for y component.

Am I missing something?

A screenshot for the specific part of the Wikipedia article (link is the link written above)

[image]

Comment: For an electron one sets $q=-1$, taking $e$ as the base unit. This explains the sign change.